# Synchronize contacts in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, synchronization

I want to be notified when some contact has been edited. I've found out many articles on the web about getting contacts, but i need synchronization.
I'm using the following code to "statically" obtain contacts:

```
private void getContacts()
{
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
    contacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);
    contacts.SearchAsync("", FilterKind.None, "query_all");
}

private void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    List<Contact> contacts = e.Results.ToList();
}
```

I need something that alert my application when contacts list changes. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: To my knowledge there isn't a mechanism to publish contacts changes to applications other than the contacts app. I think this is one of those cases where it might be worth telling us more about what you are trying to achieve so that someone can suggest an alternative approach, rather than trying to find a solution at this level

Comment: Thank for your reply Chris. I'm realizing an app that uses contacts data. So, I need update contacts data. I know that a solution to do this is to query continuously, but it's not a good solution. It would be nice to query only when an update comes.